# How to get the count of new notification's recieved

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

Ayyyy, mates! I was wondering if there was a way in Firebase to get the amount of new children added to an object. Is there anyway to do this? Please tell me if there is!

What I mean in a more logical way (silly me!) if a new object is added onto a group of objects.

[image: User object]

In the image attached above, I'm trying to get the amount of new elements added to the 'notifications' node above.

My Attempt:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(self.uid!).child("notifications").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let amountOfNotifications = snapshot.childrenCount

        })
```

JSON:

```
{
  "email" : "asdfasdf2ladjflj@aldkfj.org",
  "followers" : {
    "alsdkf" : "lkajsdlfj@ljasldf.o",
    "asdfasdf" : "ljfklasdjl;ajJ@L:KJl;kaf.daisodf",
    "asdfasdfk" : ";lkjaksldjfkl;ajsdlkf@LJ;lkjlka;jdf.omc",
    "dgsddfaf" : "lk;ajdskfljaslkj@Jlk;ajdlkfa.io",
    "follower1" : "roxyofficial@gmail.com",
    "follower10z" : "somethings@cats.io",
    "follower2" : "test@test.com",
    "follower3" : "test@test.zed",
    "follower4" : "l;kajsfkljasdflk;j@KL:Jlkajdsfl;kasdf.oio",
    "follower7" : "zed@zed.io",
    "followerte" : "testfollower@test.io",
    "folower8" : "zed>!@zedl.ocm",
    "test" : "test@io.c"
  },
  "name" : "ASDFASDF",
  "notifications" : {
    "let notification 1343936250 = new follower" : "Optional(lk;ajdskfljaslkj@Jlk;ajdlkfa.io) followed you!",
    "let notification 1588601033 = new follower" : "Optional(;lkjaksldjfkl;ajsdlkf@LJ;lkjlka;jdf.omc) followed you!",
    "let notification 1644747852 = new follower" : "Optional(somethings@cats.io) followed you!",
    "let notification 1680115082 = new follower" : "Optional(l;kajsfkljasdflk;j@KL:Jlkajdsfl;kasdf.oio) followed you!",
    "let notification 1730793657 = new follower" : "Optional(testfollower@test.io) followed you!",
    "let notification 1820028610 = new follower" : "Optional(test@test.zed) followed you!",
    "let notification 1975523553 = new follower" : "Optional(zed@zed.io) followed you!",
    "let notification 2129596138 = new follower" : "Optional(test@test.zed) followed you!",
    "let notification 2181363532 = new follower" : "Optional(;lkjaksldjfkl;ajsdlkf@LJ;lkjlka;jdf.omc) followed you!",
    "let notification 2367950713 = new follower" : "Optional(test@io.c) followed you!",
    "let notification 2409722982 = new follower" : "Optional(;lkjaksldjfkl;ajsdlkf@LJ;lkjlka;jdf.omc) followed you!",
    "let notification 2431788206 = new follower" : "Optional(zed>!@zedl.ocm) followed you!",
    "let notification 2469280631 = new follower" : "Optional(ljfklasdjl;ajJ@L:KJl;kaf.daisodf) followed you!",
    "let notification 2750686409 = new follower" : "Optional(l;kajsfkljasdflk;j@KL:Jlkajdsfl;kasdf.oio) followed you!",
    "let notification 2800426934 = new follower" : "Optional(test@test.com) followed you!",
    "let notification 2835016479 = new follower" : "Optional(testfollower@test.io) followed you!",
    "let notification 2914050639 = new follower" : "Optional(roxyofficial@gmail.com) followed you!",
    "let notification 2954110099 = new follower" : "Optional(test@test.com) followed you!",
    "let notification 2963247743 = new follower" : "Optional(zed@zed.io) followed you!",
    "let notification 3251218202 = new follower" : "Optional(zed>!@zedl.ocm) followed you!",
    "let notification 340385741 = new follower" : "Optional(testfollower@test.io) followed you!",
    "let notification 3424214838 = new follower" : "Optional(somethings@cats.io) followed you!",
    "let notification 3491288550 = new follower" : "Optional(test@test.com) followed you!",
    "let notification 3734762074 = new follower" : "Optional(ljfklasdjl;ajJ@L:KJl;kaf.daisodf) followed you!",
    "let notification 3788313156 = new follower" : "Optional(roxyofficial@gmail.com) followed you!",
    "let notification 3862281533 = new follower" : "Optional(l;kajsfkljasdflk;j@KL:Jlkajdsfl;kasdf.oio) followed you!",
    "let notification 3863677856 = new follower" : "Optional(lk;ajdskfljaslkj@Jlk;ajdlkfa.io) followed you!",
    "let notification 3867733078 = new follower" : "Optional(test@io.c) followed you!",
    "let notification 3942761365 = new follower" : "Optional(lk;ajdskfljaslkj@Jlk;ajdlkfa.io) followed you!",
    "let notification 4066943532 = new follower" : "Optional(ljfklasdjl;ajJ@L:KJl;kaf.daisodf) followed you!",
    "let notification 4083932515 = new follower" : "Optional(test@test.zed) followed you!",
    "let notification 509688728 = new follower" : "Optional(roxyofficial@gmail.com) followed you!",
    "let notification 599767405 = new follower" : "Optional(somethings@cats.io) followed you!",
    "let notification 745520426 = new follower" : "Optional(zed@zed.io) followed you!",
    "let notification 882753091 = new follower" : "Optional(test@io.c) followed you!",
    "let notification 937740183 = new follower" : "Optional(zed>!@zedl.ocm) followed you!",
    "let notification = new follower" : "Optional(test@io.c) followed you!",
    "not" : "test",
    "notification1" : "Welcome to platform!",
    "notification2" : "someIdiotFollowedYou!",
    "notification3" : "test",
    "testNot" : "alksdjf;klajsdf",
    "testNoti" : "test"
  },
  "peopleFollowing" : {
    "following1" : "dnalwodza@gmail.com",
    "following2" : "roxyofficial@gmail.com"
  },
  "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/platform-ad9e3.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2FprofileImageRIjJxqqyVdVnwqpB507SRkl2Zhf1.jpeg?alt=media&token=ea86df9e-4949-4409-b92d-3ed8db64f5de",
  "rank" : "Laksjdfklja;add",
  "userid" : "RIjJxqqyVdVnwqpB507SRkl2Zhf1"
}
```

Comment: *new children* is a relative term, What do you mean by it.

Comment: As i said your JSON tree structure as **text** not snippets, Go to your dashboard, click on the three dots on the top right of your dashboard and export your JSON and post your minimal relevant Database. (inside of the notification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am presuming that its a button which a user has to click to check its notification and every time he clicks you send a query searching for it.

Keep a separate node on your JSON structure ,

```
 {
    "email" : "asdfasdf2ladjflj@aldkfj.org",
    "followers" : {...},
    "name" : "ASDFASDF",
    "notifications" : {...},
    "peopleFollowing" : {...},
    "noOfFollwersWhenLastChecked" : 100,    //
    "profileImageUrl" : 
    "userid" : "RIjJxqqyVdVnwqpB507SRkl2Zhf1"
  }
```

Every time your user access `notifications` node , count the no of nodes there in the `notification` node and substract with `noOfFollwersWhenLastChecked` value, and replace its value with count the no of nodes there in the `notification`.

Comment: Couldn't I also make it so that when a user leaves the notificationsViewController, it deletes all the values?